# sharedObject does not save my data.

Tags: actionscript-2

```
static private function ifonEnternameFrame():Void 
{

    so.data.name = _root.getName.text;
    //trace(so.data.name);

    _root.nameBtn.onPress = function () 
    { 
        _root.gotoAndStop(2);
    }


}
```

When you start the application this code will save your name.

But when you then go to another function then it says that it's undefined.

```
    trace(so.data.name);
```

I traced this when I was on the next frame and it couldn't find the previous name.
Please help.

Comment: I answered your question. Your problem doesn't come from SharedObject.

Answer (score 0):

Flushing the shared object data is necessary to get those variables.

Use the flush function of shared object.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem doesn't come from `SharedObject`. The origin of your error message is that your `textField` *getName* is incorrectly named in your code.

If you trace *_root.getName.text* in your function *ifonEnternameFrame* you shall have the same error message:

```
trace(_root.getName.text); // undefined
```